# What is a contraction mapping?

Tags: real-analysis

> Definition: Let X be a metric space, with metric d. If $\phi$ maps X into X and if there is a number $c<1$ such that $d(\phi(x),\phi(y)) \leq c d(x,y)$ for all $x,y, \in X$, then $\phi$ is a contraction of X into X.

How to understand the contraction mapping definition intuitively? What exactly does contraction mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A contraction maps points closer together. In particular, for every $x\in X$, and any $r>0$, all points $y$ in the ball $B_r(x)$, are mapped into a ball $B_s(\large{\phi} x)$ with $s<r$ as illustrated in the figure:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It means that any two points $x$ and $y$ of $X$ having distance $d$ are sent to two points $\phi(x)$ and $\phi(y)$ having distance $d'$, with $d'<d$, hence the name of contraction.